# Displaying current Address as Toast

Tags: java, android, button, location, toast

I am writing an app and need to get the Address displayed so i can use it later.
I get the location from a LocationManager and want to display a Toast showing the Address when pressed. My problem is that, when the button is pressed, nothing happens. (Not even in LogCat)

Here's the code:

```
Button getTaxi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetTaxi);
getTaxi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void getAddress() {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        String result = null;
        try {
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                Address address = list.get(0);
                // sending back first address line and locality
                result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String exception = String.format("IOException!!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } finally {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            } else 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nix is", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

I know it's propably really messy but I just started JAVA/Android programming.

Thank you very mutch in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
Button getTaxi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetTaxi);
getTaxi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    Toast toast;

    public void getAddress() {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());   
        String result = null;
        try {
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                Address address = list.get(0);
                // sending back first address line and locality
                result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String exception = String.format("IOException!!");
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } finally {

            if (result != null) {
                toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            } else 
                toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nix is", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }




        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getAddress();
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

getAddress is not called. Add getAddress() in the onClick method.

Answer (score 2):

`public void onClick(View v)` needs to have code in it as this is what is executed when the button is pressed.  In your case, it looks like you could simply call `getAddress()` inside `onClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make onclick metod and then you have to pass getAddress() 
then after you can easily so the addreess when u click button